# How to set the scroll-thumb at the centre of the scrollbar

Tags: css, reactjs, image, scrollbar, zooming

I'm using react application and trying to display image and applying customised zoom-in/ zoom-out. Not using any library because I have to add a marker on each image and using library for zooming isn't giving proper co-ordinates for positioning marker.

I'm passing max-height and max-width to the image so that image can be viewed in its original proportion. Functions for Zoom-In and Zoom-out :

```
 zoomOut = () => {
        var myImg = document.getElementById("action-image")
        var currWidth = (myImg.style.maxWidth.split("v"))[0];
        var currHeight = (myImg.style.maxHeight.split("v"))[0];

        myImg.style.maxWidth = (Number(currWidth) - 50) + "vw";
        myImg.style.maxHeight = (Number(currHeight) - 50) + "vh";
        if (this.state.scale == 0)
            this.resetImage()
        else if (this.state.scale != 0) {
            this.setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                scale: this.state.scale - 1
            }))
        }
    }
    zoomIn = () => {
        console.log(this.state.scale);
        if (this.state.scale < 11) {
            var myImg = document.getElementById("action-image")
            var currWidth = (myImg.style.maxWidth.split("v"))[0];
            var currHeight = (myImg.style.maxHeight.split("v"))[0];
            myImg.style.maxWidth = (Number(currWidth) + 50) + "vw";
            myImg.style.maxHeight = (Number(currHeight) + 50) + "vh";
            this.setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                scale: this.state.scale + 1
            }))
        }
    }

    resetImage = () => {
        var myImg = document.getElementById("action-image")
        myImg.style.maxHeight = '95vh'
        myImg.style.maxWidth = '75.4vw'
        this.setState((state) => ({
            ...state,
            scale: 0,
        }))
    }
```

Image rendering:

```
 <RegionSelect
    maxRegions={1}
    regions={this.state.imageLoad ? [] : this.state.regions}
    regionStyle={regionStyle}
    constraint={false}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    Draggable={false}
    regionRenderer={this.regionRenderer}
 >
<img id="action-image" style={{ zIndex: 1, maxHeight: '95vh', maxWidth: '75.4vw' }} 
src={this.state.imageURL} onLoad={((load) => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    imageLoad: false,
    height: 'unset',
    width: 'unset'
   }))
  })} />
</RegionSelect>
```

[Image before zoom In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB3ng.jpg)

[Image after zoom In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INhad.jpg)

The problem is as the image is centred to maintain its aspect ratio, when the image is zoomed in,the scrollbar also should get centred which will allow to scroll upwards also. But the scroll bar starts at the top most & left most position, which makes some part(from top and left side) of image hidden.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all you need to get height of scroll-bar thumb
then you can use `window.scroll` function to set desired distance to it
why do we need height of scroll-bar thumb? because `scroll` function won't move scroll bar according to it's center

```
var arrowHeight = 25;
var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

var contentHeight = getComputedStyle(document.body).height;

contentHeight = parseFloat(contentHeight);
var viewableRatio = viewportHeight / contentHeight;

var scrollBarArea = viewportHeight - arrowHeight * 2; 

var thumbHeight = scrollBarArea * viewableRatio; 

var scrollAmount = (contentHeight / 2) - thumbHeight;

window.scroll({
    top: scrollAmount,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
```

here's the full fiddle to see how it works

https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/5ypaeo4q/5/

Comment: if you need the scroll to be both horizontal and vertical you can repeat the calculation for other size, I might update the fiddle as well

Comment: updated the fiddle, works for both directions now

Comment: Thank you ! but not getting where to add this code

Comment: @TejalC You can add it wherever you want, After Zoom IN/OUT is a good option, After Your Component loaded is good too, And please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem